# How to upload files in the downloads folder in the terminal?

Tags: file-upload, github

How to upload files in the downloads folder in the terminal?
My folder is https://github.com/rg3915/LaTeX/downloads but I can only go through the site. And when I try to download gives error.

Answer (score 1):

That usually indicates a problem during the [*upload*](https://github.com/blog/742-new-uploader-downloads-screen), making the download impossible.

See [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/github/browse_thread/thread/d4a27d78e8d231fb) for illustration:

> Try it with flash disabled.